# MATLAB-Patch between prediction bounds?

Tags: matlab, prediction, confidence-interval

I have some data fitted to an exponential function (y1) using the curve fitting app to calculate the coefficients. I then imported the model and the prediction intervals (p11; a 1441x2 matrix). (t and Asiii are imported datasets, just generated some data to explain the code)

```
S=[0.95,0.87,0.83,0.73,0.62,0.51,0.41,0.31,0.22,0.04,0.002,0,0,0,0];
t=[1,3,5,10,20,30,40,50,60,90,120,180,240,360,1440];
hold on
s2=scatter(t,Asiii,250,[0.1216, 0.8, 0.0157],'^','filled');
x = 0:1440;
y1 = 1.016*exp(-0.02349*x)
p1=plot(x,y1,'Color',[0.1216, 0.8, 0.0157],...
   'LineWidth',1.5);
p11 = predint(model,x,0.95,'observation','on');
plot(x,p11,'--','Color',[0.4235, 0.9608, .6],...
   'LineWidth',1.5);
%Patch
patch([x;x],[p11(:,1)';p11(:,2)'],'g');
%Fill
fill(x, p11,p11,'facecolor', 'red', 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facealpha', 0.4);
```

I want to have the area between the prediciton bounds/confidence intervals filled with a different color, but it seems I can only get a solid black shading using 'patch'.
[image]

[image]

I also tried using the 'fill' function but the polygons go all the way to the top of y-axis. Is there a way to adjust the Edge thickness/color?

Comment: How did the duplicate suggested on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70868109/matlab-patch-between-prediction-bounds) fail to answer your question? Simply repeating the same question without further clarification is likely to end in the same result.